# Zend MultiSelect box options are not showing

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm programing a discount creation for a web site and I'm having a problem with multiSelect box options. I tried to get values through hard coding, e.g.:

```
   $elements['apply_to'] = new \Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('apply_to');
    $elements['apply_to']->setMultiOptions(
        array(
            'iframe' => $translate->_('apply_to_iframe'),
            'iframer' => $translate->_('apply_to_iframer'),
            'unregistered' => $translate->_('apply_to_unregistered'),
            'person' => $translate->_('apply_to_person'),
            'agency' => $translate->_('apply_to_agency')
        )
    );

    $elements['apply_to']->setLabel('apply_to')
        ->setView($view)
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator(new \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty(\Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::PHP))
        ->setAttribs(array(
            'translate' => $translate
        ))
        ->setDecorators(
            array(
                array('ViewScript',
                    array(
                        'viewScript' => 'Components/Forms/Elements/Multiselect.phtml'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

And geting values from db model:

```
$elements['apply_to'] = new \Desk\Components\Forms\Elements\Multiselect('apply_to');
    $elements['apply_to']->setMultiOptions(\Desk\Models\Discounts::getApplyTo($translate));
    $elements['apply_to']->setLabel('apply_to')
        ->setView($view)
        ->setAttribs(array(
            'translate' => $translate
        ))
        ->setDecorators(
            array(
                array('ViewScript',
                    array(
                        'viewScript' => 'Components/Forms/Elements/Multiselect.phtml'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

where getApplyTo is:

```
public static function getApplyTo($translate, $not_deleted = false){
    $db = new \Db\Users();
    if ($not_deleted) {
        $rows = $db->fetchAll(array('deleted IS NULL'));
    } else {
        $rows = $db->fetchAll();
    }
    $return = array();

    if (count($rows) > 0) {
        $rows = $rows->toArray();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $return[ $row['user_type'] ] = $row['user_type'];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

But none of the examples work. Can anyone help me?